# Outlook Style - Append "banner"

Tags: html, css, outlook

i need to add a kind of banner or box to emails from outside senders in front of the mail text.
It should be on top of the mail or hovering at the most top position of the mail.

Our mail server can only add a html tag at the end of the message, but it should appear at the beginning.
I tried to add  or  with style option "position: absolute; top: 0px;" or even with fix position, but Outlook seems to ignore it.

Has anybody done something like this for Outlook or any idea what to try as there seems to be a special CSS interpretation in Outlook?

Thank you very much and kind regard,

DC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML based emails. You can read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties (HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities) in the [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.

Word considers unsupported cascading style sheet properties to be unknown properties, for example, such as `position`.